# Returning random value instead of expected values! c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Whenever I ask for the area or perimeter, it returns some absurd values.
I tried fixing it for 2 days but it is the same!
The code and the class is given below with the output!

I expect the output to be 100 but it shows

[image]

***252134578***  <<<< this

**maincode** :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rect_class.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    rectangle rect;
    int width= 10, height = 10, choice, newwidth, newheight;
    bool loop = false;
    while(loop == false){
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << " *** Menu *** " << endl;
        cout << "(1) Draw Rectangle" << endl;
        cout << "(2) Area" << endl;
        cout << "(3) Perimeter" << endl;
        cout << "(4) Resize" << endl;
        cout << "(5) Quit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice :";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;

        switch(choice){
            case 2 :cout << rect.getArea();
                break;
            case 3 : cout << rect.getPerimeter();
                break;
            case 4 : cout << "enter your height : ";
                   cin >> newheight;
                   cout << "enter your width : ";
                   cin >> newwidth;
                   rect.setHeight(newheight);
                   rect.setWidth(newwidth);
              break;
            case 5 : loop = true;
                cout << "exiting...";
                break;
            default: cout << "bro type the menu nums !!";
                break;
        }
    };
```

**rect_class.hpp**

```
class rectangle {
public :
    int getHeight() const {return itsHeight;}  //accessors
    int getWidth() const {return itsWidth;}
    void setHeight(int height){itsHeight = height;}
    void setWidth(int width){itsWidth = width;}
    int getArea();
    int getPerimeter();
private :
    int itsHeight;
    int itsWidth;
};

int rectangle::getArea(){
    return itsWidth*itsHeight;
};

int rectangle::getPerimeter(){
    return 2*(itsWidth*itsHeight);
};
```

I am in the beginning years of my programming journey,so sorry for any silly mistakes! :-)

Comment: clear your input stream before reading again

Comment: Check if adding : `cin.clear(); cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` after `cin >>` helps.

Comment: Step with the debugger.

Comment: From your output it's not clear what options you call before `setPerimeter`. Please include all the input and output that reproduces the problem. Also, you don't have to make a screenshot of the output - just copy and paste the output, that's even better than a screenshot.

Comment: Members of `rect` are not initialized. `choice == 4` should be first, then you can select choice == 3 or 2 to print rect params.

Comment: you are not assigning input at initilaization...
If user enters 3 for perimeter, in this case it is not even initialized.
That is why its providing garbage......
get it??

Comment: This is a good example of why you should strive to produce a the required [mcve] before asking a question. When you reduce the code to `int x; cout << x;` the problem's pretty easy to see.

Comment: Can you explain why you expect the output to be 100? What line of code do you think computes a result of 100 and why do you think that?

Comment: add this to the class `rectangle() : itsHeight(0), itsWidth(0) { }` should help

Comment: @user4581301 I am sorry for the disarranged question! This was my first question, so it was a bit mess! My bad!

Comment: My apologies for being unclear. My intent was not to denigrate the formatting or organization of the question What I was trying to get across is when you have a bug that is resistant to your debugging, you should remove the noise around the bug. If you can duplicate the problem with a smaller program, you are in a much better position to proceed. There is less room for the bug to hide. You can test your solutions against a much smaller program, hopefully with no other bugs, to see if they work. It is amazing how many correct fixes are discarded by people who didn't realize they had two bugs.

Comment: You probably won't have to ask a question, but if you do, it is usually easy to answer by anyone who knows the trick you have missed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rectangle` class members are not initialized. You set values for variables `int width= 10, height = 10`, but don't pass it to the `rectangle` class constructor.

Change this code:

```
rectangle rect;
int width= 10, height = 10, choice, newwidth, newheight;
```

To this:

```
int choice=0, newwidth=0, newheight=0; //always initialize variables!
rectangle rect(10, 10); //create rectangle with 10, 10
```

Now you need to add constructors to the `rectangle` class:

```
class rectangle {
public:
rectangle() = delete; //we don't need it anymore
rectangle(int width = 0, int height = 0) : itsHeight(height), itsWidth(width ) { }
//... rest of your code
```

This constructor allows you to create `rectangle` with given parameters or just create with default parameters (0,0).